# Hystrix as Circuit Breaker with ElasticSearch - desirable or use ES circuit Breaker?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, hystrix

Want to get some advice from experts around usage of Hystrix as Circuit Breaker with ES.
1. Should we use default ElasticSearch Circuit Breaker.
2. In my case tps is about 2 , considering 20x rise in request , desired hystrix thread pool would be `(peak*99p latency of request) + some buffer` ignoring `some buffer` as i already have considered 20x requests in future. My 99p latency is 40 ms, so `Thread pool = 40*0.04 = 1.6` , why should i use Hystrix or should i really need it with thread pool of 2 and a timeout catcher, i can use java native timeout for this.
Thoughts?